# Use link with image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, image, function, hyperlink

At first I want to say that I'm beginner in *Javascript*, so I can't edit my function correctly.

For now I have clickable text to remove row, but I want to use image instead of text.

This is part of function:

```
...
var removeRow = $.fn.optionTest.createColumn($("<a>", options.removeLinkOptions).text('Remove Row'));
row.append(id).append(label).append(from).append(to).append(removeRow);
```

I can't achieve correct syntax, I've tried something like, but unsuccessfully...

```
var removeRow = $.fn.optionTest.createColumn($("<a>", options.removeLinkOptions).src("http://linktoimage.com/img.jpg"));
```

Thank you for understanding and trying to help!

**UPDATE**

Later I'm using `removeRow` in following, It have `href: 'javascript:;'`, maybe that's why not working?

```
  $.fn.optionTest.defaults = {
    clearOnChange: false,
    actionId: '#action',
    indexOptions: {
      class: 'div-format-test'
    },
    rowOptions: {
      id: 'option',
      class: 'div-format',
      tag: 'tr'
    },
    fromOptions: {
      name: 'from',
      type: 'text',
      value: 'from',
      size: 20
    },
    toOptions: {
      name: 'to',
      type: 'text',
      value: 'to',
      size: 20
    },
    removeLinkOptions: {
      class: 'removeRow',
      href: 'javascript:;'
    }
  };
```

For now I've change code like:

```
var removeRow = $.fn.optionTest.createColumn($("<img>", options.removeLinkOptions).src("http://www.somelink.com/image.png"));
```

But seems like there is wrong syntax rows not appear at all now...

Comment: Does changing `<a>` to `<img>` not work?  `var removeRow = $.fn.optionTest.createColumn($("<img>", options.removeLinkOptions).src("http://linktoimage.com/img.jpg"));`

Comment: @AdamKonieska thanks for an answer, but It not working, check more details on dev35000 answer's comments.

Comment: Do you have a JS Fiddle or something where we can see more of your code and the corresponding HTML?  It will make it easier for people to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the already mentioned changing `<a>` to `<img>`, you also need to set the attribute in order to change the image source.  Using `.attr('src','...')` instead of `.src('...')` should fix it.

Changing this:

```
var removeRow = $.fn.optionTest.createColumn($("<img>", options.removeLinkOptions).src("http://www.somelink.com/image.png"));
```

To this:

```
var removeRow = $.fn.optionTest.createColumn($("<img>", options.removeLinkOptions).attr("src","http://www.somelink.com/image.png"));
```

That should fix your issue.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

use an `<img>` instead of `<a>` for an image. `<a>` is used for a link.
Thanks

Comment: You need to wrap html code with bacticks `\``, ie `\`<img>\`` for SO markup to show it

Comment: @ern its the correct answer, its just not formatted with `\`` so you cant see the code.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but It not working... After changing It rows not appears at all (rows are generated via javascript).